# ParseFile javascript - saved as bytes

Tags: javascript, pdf, parse-platform, pdf-generation

I'm trying to save PDF file as ParseFile using Parse javascript SDK:

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="profilePhotoFileUpload" onchange="selectFile(event)">
```

JS

```
function selectFile(e) {
    var fileUploadControl = $("#profilePhotoFileUpload")[0];
    var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
    var parseFile = new Parse.File("doc.pdf", file);
    parseFile.save().then(function(){
            var test = new Parse.Object("TestObject");
            test.set("file",parseFile);
            test.save();
    }, function(error) {
    });    
}
```

and i'm getting bytes result as:

http://files.parsetfss.com/637e62db-7116-473c-97dc-48ad15ce73ca/tfss-f5f522d0-0634-4e98-9f2a-be659e5dac00-asdasdas.pdf

any solution?

Comment: What output did you expect instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED**

default file data is Text.
i used FileReader to get data as base64 and then i save data like this:

```
fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = receivedText;
fr.readAsDataURL(file);

function receivedText() {           
    result = fr.result;
    var res = result.split("base64,");
    var name = "myFile.pdf";
    var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, { base64: res[1] });
    parseFile.save().then(function() {
        console.log("object saved!");
    }, function(error) {
      // The file either could not be read, or could not be saved to Parse.
    });
}
```